# Argo Error: Ambiguous reference to member ‘curry’

Tags: swift2, xcode7.1

I'm new with **Argo** on [Github](https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo/blob/master/README.md) (cause cannot use JSonModel in Swift). I got an error when create a new model but don't know how to fix.Please see image for more detail.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you already solved, but maybe this could help someone else reading the question:

On the first param the function should be map (<^>) not apply (<*>)

```
static func decode(j: JSON) -> Decoded<CountryState> {
        return curry(CountryState.init)
            <^> j <| "id"
            <*> j <| "name"
            <*> j <| "abbrev"
}
```